# function for computing bicoherence

Tags: math, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Dear all
I'm looking for a numpy/scipy function to compute bicoherence and auto-bicoherence fore the studying of 3-wave interaction. 
Thank you for all the possible help
nicola

Answer (score 3):

The best package for this in python land is http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nitime

It has several coherence estimators, but I didn't look very carefully at those. It is a package for neuroimaging, but the algorithms only use numpy and scipy, intentionally, so it can be used by other applications.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [Matlab toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3013) will help; it's quite easy to translate Matlab into Python, generally.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that relies on the scipy.spectrogram function (scipy version > 0.17) and compute the bicoherence between two signals.

Definition from Hagihira 2001 and Hayashi 2007. See [Wikipedia-bicoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicoherence)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

```
def compute_bicoherence(s1, s2, rate, nperseg=1024, noverlap=512):
    """ Compute the bicoherence between two signals of the same lengths s1 and s2
    using the function scipy.signal.spectrogram
    """
    from scipy import signal
    import numpy
    # compute the stft
    f1, t1, spec_s1 = signal.spectrogram(s1, fs = rate, nperseg = nperseg, noverlap = noverlap, mode = 'complex',)
    f2, t2, spec_s2 = signal.spectrogram(s2, fs = rate, nperseg = nperseg, noverlap = noverlap, mode = 'complex')

    # transpose (f, t) -> (t, f)
    spec_s1 = numpy.transpose(spec_s1, [1, 0])
    spec_s2 = numpy.transpose(spec_s2, [1, 0])

    # compute the bicoherence
    arg = numpy.arange(f1.size / 2)
    sumarg = arg[:, None] + arg[None, :]
    num = numpy.abs(
        numpy.mean(spec_s1[:, arg, None] * spec_s1[:, None, arg] * numpy.conjugate(spec_s2[:, sumarg]), 
        axis = 0)
        ) ** 2
    denum = numpy.mean(
        numpy.abs(spec_s1[:, arg, None] * spec_s1[:, None, arg]) ** 2, axis = 0) * numpy.mean(
            numpy.abs(numpy.conjugate(spec_s2[:, sumarg])) ** 2, 
            axis = 0)
    bicoh = num / denum
    return f1[arg], bicoh

# exemple of use and display
freqs, bicoh = compute_bicoherence(s1, s2, rate)
f = plt.figure(figsize = (9, 9))
plt.pcolormesh(freqs, freqs, bicoh, 
    # cmap = 'inferno'
    )
plt.colorbar()
plt.clim(0, 0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to normalized cross spectral density ([as defined in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28signal_processing%29))  then [matplotlib.mlab.cohere](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.cohere) would do the trick.